# Is it possible to induce erysipelas to treat cancer, under the condition that the patient is to be given antibiotics to control the erysipelas?

Tags: immunology, cancer

Dr.William Coley was one of the first to attempt fever therapy on cancer patients. He did this experiment: artificial erysipelas to treat cancer.
Coley injected Streptococcus pyogenes directly into the tumor.

My question is: if we repeat a similar experiment today, (under the condition that the patient is to be given antibiotics to control the erysipelas to avoid the ethical debacle), is it possible to develop this as a cancer immunotherapy treatment?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Ethics (incl. bioethics) is a subfield of philosophy. You should ask your question on [philosophy.SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Remi.b I very much doubt this question would be welcome on philosophy.SE

Comment: @har-wradim How about [Philosophy.SE > Biology progress and bioethics](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/12683/biology-progress-and-bioethics).

Comment: @Remi.b Maybe, but I believe we are in a better position to address this question: see my initial attempt.

Comment: See also, [wiki > ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics). `Ethics or moral philosophy is a branch of philosophy that involves systematizing, defending, and recommending concepts of right and wrong conduct.`. If you think users of Biology.SE are good at answering this question, then they should do so on Philosophy.SE. Note that there are already about a 100 posts tagged ethics (see [here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics?sort=frequent&pagesize=15)) on philosophy.SE.

Comment: My point is that this is more a procedural question: note the "considered", "standards" and "develop ... as ... treatment". The question is not whether such an undertaking would be ethical, but whether it is at all technically possible in the context of todays ethical standards as accepted in medicine and biology.

Comment: @har-wradim this is a good point, I now agree with you. I am unsure whether it is on-topic here but it would not be on-topic on philosophy.SE. Maybe Academia.SE would be a place to consider but I don't know. In the meantime I retract my close vote.

Comment: I've suggested reopening as the question is now no longer an ethical one, but is more succinctly speaking "Can a heightened immune system influence cancer treatment"? Still, the question needs further references, and perhaps a better developed explanation of the theory behind why such an idea *might* work.

Comment: I'd suggest that the question was closed because it was a question of ethics, I don't think suggesting the treatment is given with antibiotics to avoid ethical issues solves that, you can still just ask whether and how the treatment would work

Answer (score 1):

Before any experimentation on humans, any treatment undergoes an extensive testing on animal models.

Besides, there must be some degree of confidence in the potential curative effect of a remedy in order to start experiments in the first place. An experiment like the one you describe would not be approved by your institute's animal ethics commission (there is such an unpleasant but important thing) unless you prove with some line of evidence and prior knowledge that the suffering of the animals is likely not going to be in vain.

It is now also customary to provide an official approval from the ethics commission during publication submission. [You would not need such an approval for flies or worms, but for rodents (which would likely be your first test object in the case in question) or primates you would.]